# Incomplete publication WFS GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I have a polygon layer in a PostGIS database and connected it with GeoServer. When I publish the layer using a WFS service, the polygons are deformed, vertices are lost.

Where can I change GeoServer settings so that the layer is published complete?

[image]

In the image, the blue outline layer is the layer that is generated with the WFS service and the green layer is the original layer.

What GeoServer settings should I change for the WFS service layer to be published as the original layer?

Comment: Try to turn the on-the-fly simplification off https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225003/small-features-dont-draw-when-zoomed-out-using-geoserver-wms/234035#234035.

Comment: or it's a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175515/what-causes-these-geometry-differences-between-original-postgis-data-and-geoserv

Comment: Hi. thanks for the info. I already solved the problem with the answers you gave me. Thanks again